# Why does Partial View show as full page in MVC 5 Visual Studio 13?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to replace part of a page with a partial view in ASP.Net MVC 5 (Visual Studio 13) using the following:

Views/Book/Index.cshtml:

```
<div id="bargainBook">
    @Ajax.ActionLink("Click here for the Bargain Book!", 
    "BargainBook",
    new AjaxOptions
    {
        UpdateTargetId = "bargainBook",
        InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
        HttpMethod = "GET"
    })
</div>
```

In BookController:

```
public ActionResult BargainBook()
{
 var book = GetBargainBook();
 return PartialView("_BargainBook", book);
}

private Book GetBargainBook()
{
 return db.Books
     .OrderBy(b => b.Price)
     .First();
```

}

In _BargainBook.cshtml:

```
@model BookDemo.Models.Book

<div>
<p>
    <strong>Book</strong>
    @Model.Name
</p>
<p>
    <strong>Price</strong>
    @String.Format("{0:F}", @Model.Price)
</p>
</div>
```

When I click on the link, I go to a full page view of the partial page data.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Turns out that jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js is not included by default.  Adding it solved the problem.

Comment: Hi Jesse, do you know why Microsoft chose to remove the jquery.unobtrusive-ajax file from the internet template in MVC 5 versus MVC 4?  It took me a good 10 minutes wondering my my Ajax helper wasn't working.  I realize some people like to hook up their form with raw jquery, but for simple applications, I really like the MVC Ajax helpers.  Just surprised Microsoft removed the default support for them when you start a new Internet project.

Answer (score 12):

As an additional note on getting this working. I'm hoping VS 2013 RTM includes this but either way this should get you up and running

- Install jquery-validate via nuget by going to tools-library package manager->package manager console and entering in

```
install-package Microsoft.jQuery.Ajax.Unobtrusive
```

- Configure your bundle in your /app_start/bundleconfig.cs

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
    "~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive*",
    "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*")
);
```

- Add your bundle to your _layout.cshtml either beneath your

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
```

or include it in each view you want to use it in

```
@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem drove me nuts with unobtrusive Ajax in MVC with a 
begin form select list filter getting updated and the list re-displayed as a partial view. I added the first two items below but realized I also needed the last two. Once added the partial view results appeared very nicely.

```
 <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui.unobtrusive-2.1.0.js" ></script>         
 <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui.unobtrusive-2.1.0.min.js" ></script>        
 <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js" ></script>         
 <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js" ></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

1.Install  Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Ajax using NuGet

2.Add reference to Jquery and Unobtrusive in your _Layout.cshtml

@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
`<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js" >`