# Controller not returning PartialView?

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, partial-views

I have a controller which contains an if statement but it shouldn't matter if it hits the first or second block because they both return the same Type.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Descriptions(string partsNo, Details searchValue)
{
    var response = partsNo != null ? _referenceRepository.GetParts(partsNo) : _referenceRepository.SearchValue(searchValue);

    return PartialView(response);
}
```

**View**

```
@model ArrowEngineeringMVC.Models.Details

<script>
    $(document)
        .on("click",
            ".getPartNo",
            function (e) {
                var val = $(this).val();
                $.ajax({
                    url: '/Home/Descriptions',
                    contentType: 'application/json',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: JSON.stringify({ "partsNo": val }),
                    dataType: 'html'
                })
                    .success(function (result) {
                        $('#descriptionPlace').html(result);
                    })
                    .error(function (xhr, status) {
                        alert(status);
                    });
            })
</script>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Descriptions", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <div class="topBar">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Type)
        <input type="submit" id="submitId" value="submit"/>
    </div>
}

    <div class="leftPanel">
        <button href="javascript:void(0)" id="NumbersButton" value="Number" class="getPartNo">#</button>
        <button href="javascript:void(0)" value="A" class="getPartNo">A</button>
        <button href="javascript:void(0)" value="B" class="getPartNo">B</button>
        <button href="javascript:void(0)" value="C" class="getPartNo">C</button>
    </div>

    <div id="descriptionPlace"></div>
```

If you click one of the buttons it would hit the first part of the if statement. If you do this then a PartialView is returned and everything works fine, the value from the button is being passed to the controller using AJAX whereas if you do a search it is being passed via the model this is the only difference.

If you do a search it hits the second part of the if statement which doesn't return a partial view it just returns a new view for some reason.

I'm just confused because the variable **response** returns a List but just contains different values depending on which part of the if statement you hit.

Heres a bit of the **referenceRepository** just to make it easier to understand:

```
public List<Parts> SearchValue(Details searchValue)
{
    const string detailsSql = "SELECT [ID], [Description] FROM Table1 WHERE [Type] = {0}";
    string queryDetails = string.Format(detailsSql, searchValue.Type);

    var dbDetails = getConnection().Query<Parts>(queryDetails).ToList();

    return dbDetails;
}

public List<Parts> GetParts(string partNumber)
{
    string partsSql;
    if (partNumber == "Number")
    {
        partsSql = "SELECT [ID], [Description] FROM Table1 WHERE [Part Number]  not like '%[^0-9]%'";
    }
    else
    {
        partsSql = "SELECT [ID], [Description] FROM Table1 WHERE [Part Number] like '{0}%'";
    }

    string queryParts = string.Format(partsSql, partNumber);

    var dbParts = getConnection().Query<Parts>(queryParts).ToList();

    return dbParts;
}
```

Comment: @GSerg Details is an object I have created which contains a property called Type, I am posting the entire model back to the controller and the Type property will be populated

Comment: I think I misunderstood your problem description. Apparently you are saying that the partial view returned by the form replaces the entire page as opposed to going into `#descriptionPlace`. That is correct, when you submit the form, the browser displays whatever it returns as a new page. It has no idea it's not a "full" view. If you want the result of the form post to go into `#descriptionPlace`, you need to intercept the form's `submit` like you intercept the `click`s, or use `Ajax.BeginForm` with proper parameters.

Comment: @GSerg Oh yeah thank you, do you know how I would render it into the #descriptionPace using the @Html.BeginForm?

Comment: You would create another event handler for the form's `submit` event like the one you have for the buttons' `click` event that would do the same. Or you would use the [`@Ajax.*` methods](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18540745/11683).

Answer (score 0):

if you want same result as partial view in #descriptionPlace div on submit click.then you can try like this remove form tag.and bind the click event for submit buttons along with those getnumbers buttons..

Not require to post for one value? am i right?

if you want to specific about to load partial view in div or specific area then you have to mention like ajax call.or you can use @Html.Partial or RenderPartial.But your requirement little bit odd. So you can try like this..